# Getting dates in python between a past datestamp and the present

Tags: python

Language **Python**

I am wondering if anyone can help me print out some dates.

i cam trying to create a loop in which i pass in a date say **01/1/2017** and the loop will then output the first and last day in every month between then and the present day.

**Example**

```
01/01/2017
31/01/2017
01/02/2017
28/02/2017
```

etc

Any help will be appreciated

Comment: yeah well.. why do you need this?

Comment: to build a list of dates to insert into a webpage with selenium, you could hard code this but doing this will future proof it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope this will help,

**Code:**

```
from datetime import date
from dateutil.relativedelta import relativedelta
from calendar import monthrange

d1 = date(2018, 2, 26)  
d2 = date.today()

def print_month_day_range(date):
    first_day = date.replace(day = 1)
    last_day = date.replace(day = monthrange(date.year, date.month)[1])
    print (first_day.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))
    print (last_day.strftime("%d/%m/%Y"))

print_month_day_range(d1)
while (d1 < d2):
    d1 = d1 + relativedelta(months=1)
    print_month_day_range(d1)
```

**Output:**

```
01/02/2018
28/02/2018
01/03/2018
31/03/2018
...
01/07/2018
31/07/2018
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use calendar module. Below is the code:

```
import datetime
from calendar import monthrange

strt_date = '01/1/2017'
iter_year = datetime.datetime.strptime(strt_date, '%m/%d/%Y').year
iter_month = datetime.datetime.strptime(strt_date, '%m/%d/%Y').month
cur_year = datetime.datetime.today().year
cur_month = datetime.datetime.today().month

while cur_year > iter_year or (cur_year == iter_year and iter_month <= cur_month):
    number_of_days_in_month = monthrange(iter_year, iter_month)[1]
    print '/'.join([str(iter_month) , '01', str(iter_year)])
    print '/'.join([str(iter_month), str(number_of_days_in_month), str(iter_year)])
    if iter_month == 12:
        iter_year += 1
        iter_month = 1
    else:
        iter_month += 1
```

Answer (score 0):

this could work, as long as the first date you give is always the first of the month

```
from datetime import datetime
from datetime import timedelta

date_string = '01/01/2017'
date = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%d/%m/%Y').date()
today = datetime.now().date()

months = range(1,13)
years = range(date.year, today.year + 1)

for y in years:
    for m in months:
        new_date = date.replace(month=m, year=y)
        last_day = new_date - timedelta(days=1)
        if (date < new_date) & (new_date <= today):
            print last_day.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
            print new_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')

        elif (date <= new_date) & (new_date <= today):
            print new_date.strftime('%d/%m/%Y')
```

Answer (score 0):

This code would print the first and last days of all months in a year.
Maybe add some logic to iterate through the years

```
import datetime

def first_day_of_month(any_day):
    first_month = any_day.replace(day=1)
    return first_month

def last_day_of_month(any_day):
    next_month = any_day.replace(day=28) + datetime.timedelta(days=4)
    return next_month - datetime.timedelta(days=next_month.day)

for month in range(1, 13):
    print first_day_of_month(datetime.date(2017, month, 1))
    print last_day_of_month(datetime.date(2017, month, 1))
```